# MATLAB - Convert Number Character array to Number Integer array/matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, char

**My problem**: I have an array **A of type char**, that reads like this:

```
196800271010
902589451069
052068830384
901778191098
```

I want to turn A into a numerical matrix that will separate the characters into individual number integers like so

```
[1 9 6 8 0 0 2 7 1 0 1 0
 9 0 2 5 8 9 4 5 1 0 6 9
 0 5 2 0 6 8 8 3 0 3 8 4
 9 0 1 7 7 8 1 9 1 0 9 8]
```

What is the best way for this?
**I've tried**
    str2num(A), but that treats the characters as one whole number per line (Ie first line is  1.9680)
I've also tried this for loop

```
for i = 1:5 %the number of rows in the char array
    s = num2str(A(i,:));
    for t = length(s):-1:1
        result(t) = str2num(s(t));
    end
end
```

But this just returns the last line of the array, I want to have all of them.

Answer (score 4):

If you convert your matrix into a column vector, each character will be positioned in a different row, so that it can be handled independently by `str2num`. Then `reshape` back:

```
result = reshape(str2num(A(:)), size(A))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are converting twice. Just go through both indexes and convert each char and put it in the new matrix.

```
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    for t = 1:size(A,2)
        result(i,t) = str2num(A(i,t));
    end
end
```

PS: Preallocating `result` befoor the loops will increase speed:

```
result = zeros(size(A))
```

Answer (score 0):

The matrix **result1** is what you want.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots, a simple cut-and-paste will do.

Answer (score 0):

Eitan T's answer is probably best. It's cleaner and probably faster. But there are some related indexing issues to point out.

If you know the input characters are all digits, you can use a trick with Unicode character values, using the fact that the characters '0' through '9' are sequential.

```
result = double(A) - double('0');
```

Your original code *almost* works, except you're not using `i` to index in to the result, so you're rewriting a single row each pass through that outer loop. Use both indexes and the result will get its shape right.

```
for i = 1:5 %the number of rows in the char array
    s = num2str(A(i,:));
    for t = length(s):-1:1
        result(i,t) = str2num(s(t));
    end
end
```

That would get you the output you want. But there are some issues that'll crop up later. The `num2str()` call is superfluous, since the data is already char; you can just remove it. You can just use `A(i,t)` instead of `s`. And `str2double` is generally faster and safer than `str2num` since `str2num` calls `eval` behind the scenes.

But you can also just iterate through every element of a multidimensional array in one loop. This is a more general approach. When you use a single index, Matlab indexes linearly in to the array, regardless of its dimensionality.

```
result = NaN(size(s));
for i = 1:numel(s)
    result(i) = str2double(s(i));
end
```